# How much burst damage can a miracle rogue do in one turn?

Tags: hearthstone

Miracle rogue is still a popular deck, and after playing against two consecutively just now I was wondering just how much burst damage they can do in one round? I was reasonably sure in the second game that I was still in the safe range of health, but I didn't know exactly. I tried to think of the possible combos, and while I know the obvious shadow-stepped Leeroy, I'm not sure I can get all of them right as I have never played this kind of rogue.

So how much damage can a miracle rogue do in one damage, with how many cards and at how much mana? I'm not so much interested in a theoretical, but unlikely maximum, as in the combos that I can realistically expect to face in an actual game.

Comment: just curious, how much damage did you take in the second game

Comment: I have seen variations in the Miracle Rouge deck. So I guess the maximum damage output in one turn can vary from deck to deck, based on cards played in the previous turns. Wouldn't it be more correct to link to a specific miracle rouge deck?

Comment: @z' It was a badly played miracle rogue and he let the timer run out while shadow-stepping Leeroy, so I'm not sure how much damage he would have been able to cause.

Comment: The theoretical maximum from an empty board is 34. (Leeroy, 2 Shadowstep, 2 Cold Blood, 2 Prep, 2 Eviscerate) Realistically probably 22 + what is on the board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** Leeroy Jenkins has been changed to 5 mana. Since this balance change greatly affects Miracle Rogue's viability and design as a whole, I'll be leaving this answer as a historical tribute to the deck. **All information in this answer is no longer applicable!**

---

The main damage cards of Miracle Rogue are **Leeroy Jenkins** (4 Mana, 6 damage), **Eviscerate** (2 mana, 4 damage only as second card or later), **Cold Blood** (1 mana, 4 damage, only after Leeroy) and **Shadowstep** (2 mana, 6 damage, only after Leeroy). **Preparation** can be used to play a free *Eviscerate* or *Cold Blood*, I will include this option as additional damage in the following list as it's rather unlikely.

I'll split this up by mana, starting at 6 because less is really not that relevant, the fun in miracle rogue really only begins around turn 5 with the Auctioneer. Not including turn 5 itself because all the mana goes into Auctioneer there. **Be wary of the Coin!**

Note that in most cases, there will be an auctioneer on the field who does **4 additional damage**. I won't include this damage in the list because it may or may not actually be there if you get rid of it in time.

**6 Mana**

- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Eviscerate* for **10 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Shadowstep* for **12 damage**
- Any of the above + up to 2 of *Preparation* + *Cold Blood* for **+4 or +8 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + 2x *Cold Blood* for **14 damage**
- Any of the above + up to 2 of *Preparation* + *Eviscerate* for **+4 or +8 damage**

**7 Mana**

- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Eviscerate* + *Cold Blood* for **14 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Shadowstep* + *Cold Blood* for **16 damage**
- Any of the above + *Preparation* + *Cold Blood* for **+4 damage**
- Any of the above + up to 2 of *Preparation* + *Eviscerate* for **+4 or +8 damage**

**8 Mana**

- *Leeroy Jenkins* + 2x *Eviscerate* for **14 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Shadowstep* + *Eviscerate* for **16 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + 2x *Shadowstep* for **18 damage**
- Any of the above + up to 2 of *Preparation* + *Cold Blood* for **+4 or +8 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Eviscerate* + 2x *Cold Blood* for **18 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Shadowstep* + 2x *Cold Blood* for **20 damage**
- Any of the above + up to 2 of *Preparation* + *Eviscerate* for **+4 or +8 damage**

**9 Mana**

- *Leeroy Jenkins* + 2x *Eviscerate* + *Cold Blood* for **18 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Shadowstep* + *Eviscerate* + *Cold Blood* for **20 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + 2x *Shadowstep* + *Cold Blood* for **22 damage**
- Any of the above + *Preparation* + *Cold Blood* for **+4 damage**
- Any of the above + up to 2 of *Preparation* + *Eviscerate* for **+4 or +8 damage**

**10 Mana**

- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Shadowstep* + 2x *Eviscerate* for **20 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + 2x *Eviscerate* + 2x *Cold Blood* for **22 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + 2x *Shadowstep* + *Eviscerate* for **22 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Shadowstep* + *Eviscerate* + 2x *Cold Blood* for **24 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + 2x *Shadowstep* + 2x *Cold Blood* for **26 damage**
- Any of the above + up to 2 of *Preparation* + *Cold Blood* for **+4 or +8 damage**
- Any of the above + up to 2 of *Preparation* + *Eviscerate* for **+4 or +8 damage**

**11 Mana (Coin)**

- *Leeroy Jenkins* + *Shadowstep* + 2x *Eviscerate* + *Cold Blood* for **24 damage**
- *Leeroy Jenkins* + 2x *Shadowstep* + *Eviscerate* + *Cold Blood* for **26 damage**
- Any of the above + *Preparation* + *Cold Blood* for **+4 damage**
- Any of the above + *Preparation* + *Eviscerate* for **+4 damage**

Comment: This is a very nice guide, but there is one obvious point that I think should be spelled out directly. The auctioneer on the board also does 4 damage and has to be included in the calculation. And your point about the coin can't be made bold enough, of course I forgot to account for that as well and got hit by more damage than I expected.

Comment: Very good point, I added a comment about it.

Answer (score 5):

[This article has done the maths for Rogue and the other classes, too.](http://ihearthu.com/the-one-turn-kill-how-much-damage-is-possible/)

> The Rogue class was somehow more limited in this exercise by the card limit than by mana costs.  In any case, Leeroy Jenkins (4 mana) played with two Cold Blood (1 mana each), 2 Shadowstep (0 mana each, but 2 mana to return Leeroy Jenkins to the field each time), 2 Preparation (0 mana), and 2 Eviscerate (0 mana after Preparation) yields 34 damage.  In arena, the most miracle of Miracle Rogue decks could deal 91 damage (assuming the opponent lives that long) with Gadgetzan Auctioneer (4 mana), 2 Kobold Geomancer (2 mana each), a Bloodmage Thalnos (2 mana), and 13 pairs of Preparation and Eviscerate.
>
> Likelihood of happening in an actual game: the second combination is obviously impossible, while the first seems unlikely given that it takes nine cards to pull off.  Then again, never underestimate a Rogue.

Comment: Warsong Commander only gives charge to minions with 3 or less Attack. It does not work with molten giants.

Comment: Yeah, my guide was written back when Warsong Commander gave charge to all other minions. I will have to re-write the warrior part. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: I also think this answer is not helpful and does not really answer the question. The OP clearly says "I'm not so much interested in a theoretical, but unlikely maximum, as in the combos that I can realistically expect to face in an actual game." So it would be more helpful to talk about combos you actually see. Such as the 20 dmg Leeroy->Power Overwhelming->Faceless for warlocks.

Comment: I definitely answer the question, and I'll address your concern. While it's impossible to predict what the other persons deck is completely made of, you can only guess. It's rather impossible to predict a Leeroy->double PO play. You can go on forever talking about the amount of one turn kill moves each class can do.

Comment: @ChaseC, the maximum damage in one turn in construct for shaman is 48: one turn before: far sight leeroy, far sight Baron Rivendare, so you have 1 cost Leeroy and 1 cost Rivendare. In next turn: Leeroy attack- 6 damage, 1mana > double ancient spirit that Leeroy - 6 damage, 5 mana > summon 1 cost Rivendare, reincarnate Leeroy, so you will get 5 Leeroy on board ,4 Leeroy attack, 6 + 24 = 30 damage, 8 mana > coin, Rockbiter weapon and windfurry last leeroy, attack, 30 + 18 = 48 damage, 11 mana(coin). This combo cost 8 cards,the likelyhood of this happen is 0.0001%, but one can dream...

Comment: @SSilicon Oh my god, LOL. Crazy! I'll edit my answer to include your dream scenario

Comment: Better druid combo: 1 Force of Nature with 2 Savage Roar and 1 Power of the Wild => 3*7 + 4 = 25 without the Coin (with Coin add Claw for 2 additional damage => 27), and you can always add 2 Moonfire for zero Mana cost and 2 more damage

Comment: I don't understand the hunter numbers, since you can only have seven minions on the board.  If you dropped 7 timber wolves and played UTH, all your hounds would be immediately destroyed due to lack of board space.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you pare down this answer to just the question asked. The question only asks about Miracle rouge damage. If people are searching for "Max Warlock damage in one turn" it would not lead to your answer here.

Comment: This answer is copied word-for-word from [a November 2013 ihearthu.com article](http://ihearthu.com/the-one-turn-kill-how-much-damage-is-possible/).  This explains (among other things) the hunter numbers which have confused some; at that time Unleash the Hounds costed 1 mana and read "Give your Beasts +1 Attack and Charge."

Comment: If you're going to copy someone else's content, **please** cite it so that others know where you're coming from.  Otherwise you are guilty of plagiarism.

Comment: It appears that the site in question was cited in a previous revision.  However, the current revision does not have any citation and I expect many of the upvoters thought this was your own work.

Comment: @Goos Okay, sorry about that. Added the source.

Comment: @Sorean Okay, I edited my answer to only include the Rogue.

Comment: When it comes to referencing other people's work, things get tricky.  The best idea is to summarize the content behind the link in your own words, and then provide a link for reference.  If you must, you can quote a small part of it to support your answer and provide a source link, although this is a bit riskier.  It's a bad idea to either just provide a link ("your answer is here") or to quote a big chunk of the article without adding to it, sourced or not ("this comes from here: {lots of article text word for word}").

Comment: @agent86 Right, understood. Won't happen again. Thanks for clarifying everyone. I have frequented ihearthu for a long time and just happened to remember this article as interesting a while ago. So I looked it up as the answer to the question. I also figured I'd give the other classes, but the article in question was outdated, and it was also suggested that I only answer the question stated.

Comment: the original question is not just looking for a theoretical maximum but also a average reasonable expectation of damage from miracle rogues.

Comment: The average damage expectation goes up as the match goes on, and the rogue collects more of the needed cards into his hand.